# Where can I find a pie pan with heavily slanted sides?

Tags: pan

I'm trying to duplicate a Portuguese Sweet Bread that appears to be baked in a pan that's 2" deep, with slanted sides such that the inside diameter goes from 6 1/2" at the bottom to 7 3/4" at the top.

The bread looks something like this:

[Portuguese Sweetbread](https://azoreangreenbean.com/2015/12/portuguese-sweetbread/)

Anyone know where I can find a pan like this?

Comment: As the bread didn't mushroom out at the top, the dish is likely taller than the sides of the bread.  If the bottom is only 6.5" across, I'd likely be looking for something 4" or higher on the sides ... which is getting into just stoneware serving bowl type things, not pie pans (at least in the US, that's usually reserved for things with really low sides)